# Memset with assignment

Tags: c++, memset

I have a problem : "Multiple test (t test), each test prints all strings with length N and contains exactly H numbers 1."

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long LL;

LL t,N,H;
LL arr[1000];
bool used[1000];
LL num = 0;

void show(){
    LL number = 0;
    for (LL u = 0; u<1000; u++)
    {
        if (arr[u]==2)
        {
            number++;
        }
    }
    if (number==H)
    {
        for (LL v = 0; v<1000; v++)
        {
            if (arr[v])
            {
                cout << arr[v] - 1;
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void backtrack (LL pos){
    if (pos==N+1)
    {
        num = 0;
        show();
        return;
    }
    if (!used[pos])
    {
        for (LL j = 1; j<=2; j++)
        {
            if (j==2)
            {
                if (num==H)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    num++;
                }
            }
            arr[pos] = j;
            used[pos] = true;
            backtrack(pos+1);
            used[pos] = false;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin >> t;
    for (LL i = 0; i<t; i++)
    {
        cin >> N >> H;
        //memset(arr, sizeof(arr), 0);
        for (LL cv = 0; cv<1000; cv++)
        {
            arr[cv] = 0;
        }
        backtrack(1);
        if (i<t-1)
        {
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I had trouble with using "memset(arr, sizeof(arr), 0);" - it returned wrong answer. But with the same test, when I used for-loop to assign all elements in array "arr" equal to 0, it returned correct answer.

My test is:
2
4 2
3 1

I am asking to know the difference between memset and for-loop (using for assignment). Thanks.

Comment: The arguments for [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) are dest, value, size; rather than  what you're showing: dest, size, value.

Answer (score 3):

`memset` takes three arguments.The first is the pointer to the block of memory to fill (your `arr`), the second is the value to set, and the third the number of bytes to fill.
 [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)'s the documentation for `memset`, if you want to go deeper.
In your code I read

```
memset(arr, sizeof(arr), 0)
```

That reads as "fill 0 bytes with the value of sizeof".
 You've only given the wrong arguments, it sould be:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr))
```

Comment: BTW, a recent GCC might spot that mistake when compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra` and give some warning

Comment: I didn't know that, nice. You say GCC, can I assume this is for g++ too?

Comment: Yes, both `gcc` & `g++`  are commands from [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), the GNU Compiler *Collection*

Answer (score 1):

memset's second argument should be **value** and third is size. Use this:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr) );
```

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) for details.